# Rank of idempotent matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, matrix-rank, idempotents, projection-matrices

Let $B_1, B_2, \dots, B_k$ be idempotent matrices, i.e., $B_i^2=B_i$. Can we prove that

$$\mbox{rank}(I-B_1\cdots B_k)\leq \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \mathrm{rank}(I-B_i)$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** The inequality is true for general $B_i$s. Idempotence is not needed (thanks to robinson for his/her comment.)
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{rank}(I-AB)
&= \mathrm{rank}(I-A+A-AB)\\
&\le \mathrm{rank}(I-A)+\mathrm{rank}(A-AB)\tag{1}\\
&= \mathrm{rank}(I-A)+\mathrm{rank}(A(I-B))\\
&\le \mathrm{rank}(I-A)+\mathrm{rank}(I-B)\tag{2},
\end{align*}
where $(1)$ is due to the fact that [$\mathrm{rank}(X+Y)\le\mathrm{rank}(X)+\mathrm{rank}(Y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59459/show-that-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornameranka-operatorname?rq=1) and $(2)$ is due to the inequality [$\mathrm{rank}(XY)\le\min\left(\mathrm{rank}(X), \mathrm{rank}(Y)\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978/how-to-prove-and-interpret-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornamemin-ope?lq=1).
Apply the displayed inequality recursively, we get the result.

Comment: Seems like you don't need idempotence for step (2)

Comment: @user1551 Year, as robinson said, the idempotence is not used in (2). since we have $rank(AB)\leq \min(rank(A),rank(B))$.

Comment: @robinson Thanks. Edited.

Comment: @XLDD Thanks. Actually I noticed that too when I wrote my answer, but the inequality rank(AB) <= rank(A) is more obvious when A is idempotent than in the general case. So, I used idempotence as the reason then.