# Show $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \ge \operatorname{rank}(A+B)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-rank

> Show $\operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B) \ge \operatorname{rank}(A+B)$, where $A,B \in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{F})$.

I'm trying to think in terms of linear transformations.
We can define $T_a, T_b:\mathbb{F}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{F}^m$.
I know that $\dim_{\mathbb F}\operatorname{Im} T_a, \dim_{\mathbb F}\operatorname{Im} T_b \le m$.

What should I do next?

Comment: See also: [Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A+B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59459)

Comment: See also accepted answer to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877802/rank-of-a-matrix-sum/877806#877806

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Hint:** It suffices to prove that $C(A+B)\subseteq C(A)+C(B)$, because
$$\begin{align} C(A+B)\subseteq C(A)+C(B) &\implies \dim \left(C(A+B)\right)\leq \dim \left(C(A)+C(B)\right)\\
&\implies \text{rank}(A+B) \leq \dim(C(A))+\dim(C(B))-\dim(C(A)\cap C(B)).\end{align}$$

Comment: Hmm.. the columns of $C(A+B)$ are linear combination of the columns of $C$. Is that what the hint leading to?

Comment: @AnnieOK $C(X)$ denotes the [column space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_space) (or range).

Comment: Maybe: Since every $C(A+B)_i$ is a linear combination of $C(A)_i, C(B)_i$ then we can conclude $C(A+B) \subseteq C(A) + C(B)$? Is that right?

Comment: @AnnieOK That proves the inclusion, yes. But I'd rather do it like this: let $X\in C(A+B)$, then $X=(A+B)x$, for some $x$, thus $X=\underbrace{Ax}_{\in C(A)}+\underbrace{Bx}_{\in C(B)}$.

Comment: Great, I get it now :)

Comment: Comment, down voter?

Comment: @GitGud in your comment why X=(A+B)x for some x?

Comment: @gbox It's the definition of $C(M)$ for a $p\times q$ matrix $M$, more precisely $C(M):=\{Mx\colon x\in \mathbb R^{q\times 1}\}$.

Comment: @GitGud shouldn't it be xM? thanks

Comment: @gbox [No](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_space#Definition).

Comment: @GitGud sorry you are right, my bad

Comment: Nice solution +1!

Answer (score 7):

How about this: Let $rk A: =a$ , $rk B:=b$. Now we can do Gaussian elimination on both, to end with two matrices $A'$, $B'$ with , respectively, $a$ and $b$ non-zero rows. But the sum $A'+B'$ will have at most max{a,b} nonzero rows. Then $a+b \geq$ Max{$a,b$}

Comment: I like this solution, though it somewhat technical/arithmetical.

Comment: Thanks; do you want to suggest changes?

Comment: Oops.. auto-correct made it arithmetical. I meant "algorithmical" (If that's a word). The proof is $100$ percent fine, I just want to understand it through another perspective.

Comment: But if you are doing Gaussian elimination on both of them independently, you can't really just add them like that in the end. You have $A'+B' = E_1 A E_1^{-1} + E_2 B E_2^{-1}$, which does not really say much about $A+B$.

Comment: $rank(A+B)$ is equal to $rank((A+B)')$, but not necessarily equal to $rank(A'+B')$

Comment: I was thinking exactly along your lines (because it applies to the product AB), but then I wondered why is this constraint so loose?  Why not say $rank(A+B) \le max(rank(A), rank(B))$, instead?  Then I thought of a counterexample.  Let `A = [1 0; 2 0]` and `B = [0 4; 0 3]`.  `A + B = [1 4; 2 3]` (Julia notation).  Then the ranks of A and B are 1, but the rank(A+B) = 2.  So there is some faulty logic in this proof.