# Rank of a Matrix Sum

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-rank

I have $3\times3$ matrices such that $S=A+B$. I know there is an inequality connecting rank of the matrices $A$, $B$ and its sum $S$. Could you write down that here? It will be a great help for me.

Means equation  or inequality connecting $\operatorname{rank}(S)$, $\operatorname{rank}(A)$ and $\operatorname{rank}(B)$.

Comment: need a general one .. Is this correct? $\operatorname{rank}(A+ B) \le \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)\ ?$

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851596/show-rka-rkb-ge-rkab/851600#851600).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The rank does not behave well under sum

Example $0=A+(-A)$ for any $A$.

On the other hand, the rank is subadditive:

> $\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\leq\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)$

*Proof*. I denote by "span of a set" the vector space generated by that set.

The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the span of the set of its columns. The span of the columns of $A+B$ is contained in the span of {columns of $A$ and columns of $B$}.

**Edit.** From a comment:

Let $C_A$ be the span of the columns of $A$ and $C_B$ the span of the columns of $B$. Let $c=\dim(C_A\cap C_B)$. The span of the columns of $A+B$ is contained in the span of $C_A\cup C_B$.

Then $$\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\leq \dim(C_A)+\dim(C_B)-\dim(C_A\cap C_B)=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)-c.$$

Now, let $R_A$ be the span of the rows of $A$ and $R_B$ the span of the rows of $B$. Let $d=\dim(R_A\cap R_B)$.

Since the rank by columns equals the rank by row we have 
 $$\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\leq \dim(R_A)+\dim(R_B)-\dim(R_A\cap R_B)=\operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)-d.$$

In conclusion
 $$\operatorname{rank}(A+B)\leq \operatorname{rank}(A)+\operatorname{rank}(B)-\max\{c,d\}.$$

Comment: need bit more tight one..Some thing like this.(http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/PUB/Doutorado/2012-Biller/Marsaglia1964.pdf). I am bit confused by the meaning of c and d in the lin-pdf,else it would have been sufficient

Comment: It would be nice something if we get something like  sylvesters law on matrices

Comment: what is your doubt? c and d are well defined in the linked pdf

Comment: "Span of the colum" What do you mean? please give a simple  example

Comment: the space generated by the columns

Comment: means the non vanishing columns?