# rank(a+b) ≤ rank(a) + rank(b) proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I have searched through the Internet for a proof, but didn't find anything. Can someone give me a full proof of this:

let $a,b$ be matrix $nxn$, prove:

$rank(a+b) ≤ rank(a) + rank(b)$

Comment: Already solved at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877802/rank-of-a-matrix-sum

Comment: Can someone give me a reference to an online book where can I see full proof?

Answer (score 8):

Let $x_1,\ldots, x_m$ be a basis of the rowspace of $a$ and $y_1,\ldots, y_n$ be the basis of the rowspace of $b$. If every row of $a+b$ can be written as a linear combination of $x_1,\ldots,x_m,y_1,\ldots, y_n$ then $rk(a+b)\leq m+n=rk(a)+rk(b)$. But that's obvious.