# additivity of rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

we know that for all $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ :
$$
rank (A+B)\leq rank(A)+rank (B) 
$$
see [here for a simple proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851596/show-operatornameranka-operatornamerankb-ge-operatornameranka), but for which condition on  the coefficients of $A$ and $B$ we can obtain a perfect equality.

more simply if we assume that $rank(A)=1$ what will be the condition on $B$ to have :
$$
rank(A+B)=rank(B)+1
$$

Comment: It is necessary, but not sufficient, that the augmented matrix $[A \; B]$ have rank $rank(A) + rank(B)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer here [WHEN DOES $RANK(A+B) = RANK(A) + RANK(B)?$](http://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cmb/v15/cmb1972v15.0451-0452.pdf) 
the answer is that :
$$
R(A)\cap R(B)=0 \\
R(A^*)\cap R(B^*)=0 
$$