# Proof that left singular vectors in SVD are orthogonal, and proof of low-rank approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I've been reading about SVDs and have a couple questions. First, let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ be a matrix with SVD $U\Sigma V^T$. Let $\sigma_i$ denote the $i$'th singular value, with corresponding right singular vector $v_i$. Is there a simple proof, using elementary linear algebra, for why the left singular vectors, $Av_i$'s, are orthogonal. Secondly, is it true that $A_k=\sum_{i=1}^kAv_iv_i^T$ is always of rank $k$, where $k\le \text{rank}(A)$?

Comment: Here is an animation of a low rank approximation: [Low rank approximation using the singular value decomposition][1]


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pAiVb7gWUrM

Answer (score 2):

left singular vectors is by definition a unit vector $v_i$ such that :
$$
Av_i=s_i w_i \qquad A^tw_i=s_i v_i 
$$
then :
$$
AA^tw_i=s_i A v_i= s_i^2 w_i
$$
so $s_i^2$ are the eigenvalues of the hermitian matrix $AA^t$ with corresponding eigenvectors $w_i$ so $w_i$ will be orthonormal, in fact it suffices to show that $w_i$ are orthogonal, let $s_i\neq s_j$ :
$$
s_i^2\langle  w_i , w_j \rangle =\langle s_i^2 w_i , w_j \rangle = \langle AA^tw_i , w_j \rangle=\langle w_i ,  AA^tw_j \rangle=\langle  w_i ,s_j^2 ww_j \rangle=s_j^2\langle  w_i , w_j \rangle  
$$
so $\langle w_i , w_j\rangle =0$ this implies that 
$$
\langle Av_i , Av_j\rangle=\langle s_i w_i , s_jw_j\rangle=s_i s_j\langle w_i , w_j\rangle=0
$$
for the second question of rank we will use some simple fact about rank, which you can see them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)#Properties) :
$$
rank(Ab)\leq \min(rank(A),rank(B))\\
rank(A+B)\leq rank(A)+rank(B)
$$
so we know that the matrix $v_iv_i^t$ is of rank one (because $(v_iv_i^t)x=\langle v_i , x \rangle v_i$ forall $x$) and then for all $i$ the matrix $Av_i v_i^t$ is of rank one (if we assume surly that $A\neq 0$), so 
$$
rank(A_k)=rank(\sum_{i=1}^k A v_i v_i^t ) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k rank(A v_i v_i^t)=k
$$
to verify the equality we can use [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831205/additivity-of-rank) (because the answer of the question remain true for $n\times d$ matrix) and to see that 
$$
Ran(Av_iv_i^t)=\mathbb{R}(Av_i)\\
Ran((Av_iv_i^t)^t)=Ran(v_iv_i^t A^t )=\mathbb{R} v_i 
$$
(because $Ran(v_i v_i^t)=\mathbb{R} v_i $)

so for $i\neq j$ :
$$
Ran(Av_iv_i^t)\cap Ran(Av_jv_j^t)= \mathbb{R}(Av_i) \cap \mathbb{R}(Av_j)=\{0\} \;\textrm{Orthogonality from the first question }\\
Ran((Av_iv_i^t)^t)\cap Ran((Av_jv_j^t)^t)=\mathbb{R} v_i \cap \mathbb{R} v_j =\{0\} \; \textrm{Orthogonality with the same argument  }
$$
so $Rank(A_k)=k$.