# How To Prove Left Singular Vectors Are Orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, alternative-proof, orthogonality, svd, singular-values

For SVD, for a matrix $A$ that is $m~\times~n$, we select the right singular vectors as

$$
\mathbf{v_1}
\equiv
\text{arg max}_{\mathbf{v}:\vert\mathbf{v}\vert=1}\vert{A\mathbf{v}}\vert
$$

$$
\mathbf{v_i}
\equiv
\text{arg max}_{\mathbf{v}\perp\mathbf{v_1},...,\mathbf{v}\perp\mathbf{v_{i-1}},\vert\mathbf{v}\vert=1}\vert{A\mathbf{v}}\vert
$$

And we select the singular values and left singular vectors as 
$$
\sigma_{1}\equiv\text{max}_{\mathbf{v}:\vert\mathbf{v}\vert=1}\vert A\mathbf{v}\vert
$$
$$
\sigma_{i}\equiv\text{max}_{\mathbf{v}\perp\mathbf{v_1},...,\mathbf{v}\perp\mathbf{v_{i-1}},\vert\mathbf{v}\vert=1}\vert A\mathbf{v}\vert
$$
$$
\mathbf{u_i}\equiv\frac{A\mathbf{v_i}}{\sigma_{i}}
$$
How can I prove that the $\mathbf{u_i}$'s, the left singular vectors, are orthogonal? I know of the proof by induction, but I was wondering if there is a simpler proof?

I have read this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1838857/515257

But that answer assumes that $A^T\mathbf{u_i}=\sigma_i\mathbf{v_i}$. But I'm not making that assumption. Or is there a way to derive that?

Comment: What is the proof by induction that you know?

Comment: I wrote an explanation here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/403924/43159

Answer (score 2):

It can be derived using the Gramian matrix and Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization Process, and the Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization Process ensures that the singular vectors are orthonormal and hence orthogonal. For more information please refer to this tutorial: [Singular Value Decomposition Tutorial](https://davetang.org/file/Singular_Value_Decomposition_Tutorial.pdf).