# How to prove this matrix is rank n?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

Let $M = \begin{pmatrix} p_0 (1- p_0) & -p_0 p_1 &\ldots & p_0 p_n\\
-p_1 p_0 & p_1 (1-p_1) & \ldots & p_1 p_n\\
\vdots & & &\vdots\\
-p_np_0 &\ldots&&p_n(1-p_n)\end{pmatrix}$ where $\sum_i p_i = 1$ and $p_i >0$ for all i. How to show this matrix has rank n?

For clarity, $M_{i,j} = p_i(\delta_{ij} - p_j)$ and $\delta_{ij} = 1$ if $i = j$ and 0 otherwise, where $\sum_i p_i = 1$ and $p_i >0$.

I tried random values of $\{p_0, \ldots, p_n\}$ and it consistently returns n, so hoping for the rank be n.

Comment: The matrix as you have written it is $(n+1)\times(n+1)$.  If $n=1$ it's a $2\times2$ matrix with rank $1$.  I think you mean to conjecture that the matrix has rank $n$.

Comment: yes, I will update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your matrix is $$M=D-uu^\top$$

, where $D=\text{diag}(p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_n)$ and $u=(p_0,p_1,\ldots,p_n)^\top$

Consequently, $$\operatorname{rank}(M)\ge |\text{rank}(D)-\operatorname{rank}(uu^\top)|=n+1-1=n$$

The matrix $M$ of order $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ is related to the dispersion matrix of a singular multinomial distribution ('singular' because of the restriction $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n p_k=1$). Hence rank of $M$ is at most $n$.

This is also [seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) from the fact that $$\det M=\left(\prod_{k=0}^n p_k\right)\left(1-\sum_{k=0}^n p_k\right)=0$$

So, $\operatorname{rank}(M)=n$.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you elaborate on $rank(M) \geq n$? I agree rank(D) = n+1 and $rank(uu^T) =1$ but how is $rank(M) \geq \| rank(D) - rank(u u^T)\|$?

Comment: @listener It follows from $$\text{rank}(\color{green}{A-B}+\color{blue}B)\le \text{rank}(\color{green}{A-B})+\text{rank}(\color{blue}B)$$ for any two matrices $A$ and $B$ having the same order.

Comment: @listener https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851596/show-operatornameranka-operatornamerankb-ge-operatornameranka?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works.

Comment: Good point for the connection with covariance matrix (preferable to "confusion matrix") of a multinomial ; for this, refer to page 5 of https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse312/20su/files/student_drive/5.8.pdf

Answer (score 3):

For a start: if you add every other row to the first row you get a zero row because
$$p_0(1-p_0)-p_1p_0-\cdots-p_np_0=p_0-p_0(p_0+p_1+\cdots+p_n)=0$$
in the first column, and similarly for all other columns.  So the rank of the $(n+1)\times(n+1)$ matrix is at most $n$.

Sorry but I gotta go now.  Hope somebody else can finish the problem by showing that the rank is not less than $n$.

Comment: To complete David answer, once we know the rank is $<n+1$, it suffices to find a $n\times n$ sub-matrix which has a non-zero determinant.