# How can you calculate the rank of an nxn matrix with the given conditions?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-rank, gaussian-elimination

Let $A=(a_{i,j})$ a square matrix whose elements are:

- $0$ if $i=j$.
- $1$ if $j>i$.
- $-1$ if $j<i$.

Is there a simple way to find its rank?

Comment: Have you tried small examples?  To what observation did they lead to?

Comment: They seem to lead to the following conclusion:

If the matrix is nxn, the rank will be n if n is even and n-1 if it's odd.

Comment: first you work it out by hand for $n=1,2,3,4$ I think I will fiddle with this; there is what Newman, pages 56-60 calls the Skew Normal Form, related to the Smith normal form.  The outcome is that, for a unimodular matrix $P,$  we construct $P^T A P = B,$   where the elements of $B$ are integers when $j = i+1$ and their negatives when $j=i-1,$ otherwise all zero.  https://books.google.com/books?id=jEKFYutSGGYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Answer (score 1):

that was neat. Same rank as the matrix with entry $1$ when $j=i+1,$ then $-1$ when $j=i-1,$ otherwise $0$

Congruence:

$$ \tiny
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&0&0&0 \\
0&-1&1&0&0 \\
0&0&-1&1&0 \\
0&0&0&-1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
0&1&1&1&1\\
-1&0&1&1&1 \\
-1&-1&0&1&1 \\
-1&-1&-1&0&1 \\
-1&-1&-1&-1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&1&-1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&-1&0 \\
0&0&0&1&-1 \\
0&0&0&0&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
0&1&0&0&0 \\
-1&0&1&0&0 \\
0&-1&0&1&0 \\
0&0&-1&0&1 \\
0&0&0&-1&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The final matrix is the Skew Normal Form in [Newman, especially pages 56-60.](https://books.google.com/books?id=jEKFYutSGGYC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

> The process is now repeated with $E$ until the canonical form
> described by the theorem is obtained, and the procedure makes it clear
> that the rank of $A$ must be even.

Once the matrix is in this normal form, the new null  (zero eigenvector)vector(s) becomes quickly  apparent: none when $n$ even, exactly one when $n$ is odd, namely $(1,0,1,0,1)^T$ and multiplied by any constant.

Answer (score 1):

checking the determinant, we see that
$\det\big(A\big)= \det\big(A^T\big)= \det\big(-I_nA\big)= \det\big(-I_n\big)\cdot\det(A\big) = (-1)^n\cdot \det(A\big)$
so  $n$ is odd$\implies$$A$ is singular.

**Now it suffices to show that the matrix is invertible if $n$ is even.** (When $n$ is odd, let $n':=n-1$ and consider the leading $n'\times n'$ principal submatrix -- if we show this is invertible, then $\text{rank}\big(A\big) = n'$.)

I suspect you're working over reals.  Since all components of $A$ are integers, we may as well change the field to rationals, $\mathbb Q$ which doesn't change rank, ref [Does real dimension equal rational dimension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3777401/does-real-dimension-equal-rational-dimension/)

By assumption $n$ is even and it suffices to show $\det\big(A\big)\%2 \neq 0$. This is equivalent to changing the field to $\mathbb F_2$ and then calculating the determinant.

In $\mathbb F_2$ we have $A= - I+\mathbf {11}^T= I+\mathbf {11}^T$
(note: since $-1=1$ in $\mathbb F_2$, then $-I=I$)

By the matrix determinant lemma:
$$
\begin{align}    
&\det\big(A\big)\\   
&= \det\big(I+\mathbf {11}^T\big)\\  
&= \det\big(I\big)\cdot \big(1+\mathbf {1}^T(I)^{-1}\mathbf 1\big)\\  
&= 1\cdot \big(1+\mathbf {1}^T\mathbf 1\big)\\
&=1\cdot \big(1+0\big)\\  
&= 1  
\end{align}
$$
noting that $\mathbf {1}^T\mathbf 1 = \big(\sum_{k=1}^n 1\big) = 0 $ in $\mathbb F_2$ since $n$ is even.

Thus when $n$ is even, $\det\big(A\big)$ is odd, and therefore non-zero, which completes the proof.

Comment: they wanted the rank when the matrix is singular..

Comment: you are 12 seconds early -- I had bumped the submit button while still editing somehow

Comment: good work. I do the same thing, I get part of the answer typed up, see that it came out legible, then type the next section. Often I get downvotes in the middle

Comment: it's brutal -- I think pressing 'return' will bring me to the next line to type more and yet somehow it becomes 'submit'

Comment: For the first few years I composed most answers in Latex on my home computer. I still do that for longer answers that have some interest for me. The tex file renders into about 300 pdf pages now; of course, I just make a pdf of the last few pages that have the current answer in progress. Easier for me to read and proofread than on MSE.

Comment: I think there is a simple argument to show that a zero eigenvector has a very special form, forced on it by some kind of back substitution; anyway, when singular, the zero eigenspace has dimension one.

Comment: Why $det(A^{T})=det(-I_nA)$?

Comment: your $A$ has zeros on the diagonal, 1's above the diagonal and -1's below the diagonal.  This means that $A$ is *skew symmetric* i.e. $A^T = -A= -I_n A$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sneakier solution.
It suffices to prove $n-1\leq \text{rank}\big(A\big)$

$R:=A +\mathbf{11}^T$
$R$ has zeros below the diagonal so it is *upper triangular* and it has ones on the diagonal so $\text{rank}\big(R\big)=n$.  Rank is sub-additive (ref: [Show that $\operatorname{rank}(A+B) \leq \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{rank}(B)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/59459/show-that-operatornamerankab-leq-operatornameranka-operatorname)) so we have

$n =\text{rank}\Big(R\Big) = \text{rank}\Big(A +\mathbf{11}^T\Big)\leq \text{rank}\Big(A \Big) + \text{rank}\Big(\mathbf{11}^T\Big)=\text{rank}\Big(A\Big) + 1$
$\implies n-1\leq \text{rank}\Big(A\Big)$

====
**(i)** When $n$ is odd, since $A=-A^T$, checking the determinant, we see that $\det\big(A\big) = 0$, so $n-1\leq \text{rank}\Big(A\Big)\leq n-1$, i.e. $\text{rank}\Big(A\Big) = n-1$.

**(ii)** Now for even $n$, the above tells us $\text{rank}\Big(A\Big)\in\big\{n-1,n\big\}$.
$\text{rank}\Big(A\Big)=n-1\implies A$ has an $n-1\times n-1$ principal submatrix that is invertible, see [Prove the existence of a principal submatrix of order $r$ in $M\in\Bbb F^{n\times n}, M=-M^T,\ \operatorname{rank}(M)=r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718534/prove-the-existence-of-a-principal-submatrix-of-order-r-in-m-in-bbb-fn-time/)  but this invertible $n-1\times n-1$ principal submatrix is odd dimensional and skew symmetric, so it must have a determinant of zero, a contradiction.  Thus for even $n$, we know $\text{rank}\Big(A\Big)=n$

Comment: What is $11^T$?

Comment: $\mathbf 1$ is an n-dim vector filled with ones, so $\mathbf {11}^T$ is an $n\times n$ matrix filled with ones